# Will a stylus work with my HTC Sensation?

Tags: stylus, htc-sensation

I'm interested in buying a stylus pen for my HTC Sensation.

Do these work on the HTC Sensation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTC Sensation uses a capacitive touchscreen, so any standard [capacitive stylus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_sensing#Capacitive_stylus) will work for touch-based input. Simply be sure you don't purchase a stylus designed for a [resistive touchscreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistive_touchscreen).